# Undefined function 'entity_metadata_wrapper'

Tags: entities, 9

A custom module is using the following code.

```php
function sun_blogs_views_pre_render(&$view) {
        //......
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
        $title = $wrapper->field_job_title->value();
        if (strlen($title)) {
          $view->description .= ' - '  . $title;
        }
      }
      Drupal::service('views.breadcrumb')->setBreadcrumb($breadcrumbs);
    }
  }
}
```

It causes the following error.

> Undefined function 'entity_metadata_wrapper'.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: entity_metadata_wrapper() does not exist in Drupal 8 or Drupal 9. It does not appear that your custom module has been ported to D8/9 yet.

Comment: $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node); what is the alternative for this , can you help ,me out.

Comment: As @anonymous said, function entity_metadata_wrapper does not exit. You just replace with $node->field_job_title->value to get value of title.

Answer (score 1):

[`entity_metadata_wrapper()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/entity/-/blob/7.x-1.x/entity.module#L1409) is a function implemented by the Drupal 7 version of the Entity API module. Since it returns a class wrapping the `stdClass` instance used from Drupal core for entities objects, and since Drupal 8 doesn't use  `stdClass` objects for entities, that function isn't anymore necessary.

In Drupal 8, and Drupal 9, you access that field with `$node->field_job_title->value` or `$node->get('field_job_title')->getValue()`.